# How to connect a YX5300 serial mp3 player module to esp32?

Tags: mp3, esp32, include-path, arduino-esp32, software-serial

I'm pretty new to IOT and esp32 but so far managed to learn by myself, however, when I tried connecting a YX5300 serial mp3 module to my esp32 I have struggled to even make the #include libraries work.

I am using vscode along with platformio and I installed the "SerialMP3Player" library in my project to make it work.

After installing the library to my project i got errors saying that the "SoftwareSerial" library needs to be installed aswell, so I installed it and now, after doing that, my current error is this:

[the build error i recieved after installing both libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGkNC.png)

So my question is  what to do now? continue to find and install libraries that pop up in build errors or am i just missing something obvious?

Also, is it even possible to connect this module to an esp32 board? I only came across examples using arduino board variants.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi BOG33, welcome to SO. Please copy and paste any text output into your post as text, surrounded by code tags (instead of an image).

Answer (score 0):

The SoftwareSerial library is meant for Microchip Atmega microcontrollers. Most likely nobody has ever bothered to use this device's library (SerialMP3Player) with other devices, you might be the first to port it to ESP32 - if you feel up to the task.

After a quick look this doesn't seem very difficult - the code looks to be quite well abstracted and only talks to the SoftwareSerial library. You'd need to replace that with something that works on ESP32. I'd suggest a regular old HardwareSerial which uses a hardware UART - there are plenty of those on ESP32.

Comment: haha well, Im not looking to try something nobody has done before, not sure where to even begin...

Im just looking to find a quick and easy way of playing a single song, while using my esp32 board (for a basic alarm clock application prototype). preferably through a module the saves me the trouble of encoding mp3 files

have any suggestions?